# High CPU in jetty 6 when using jetty 6 server and Jetty Proxy servlet

Tags: jetty, cpu-usage

Scenario: Jetty server is configured to use Blocking connector and the servlet deployed in the jetty server is forwarding the request to other application using jetty httpclient(configured using CONNECTOR_SELECT_CHANNEL) using exchanges.

Sometimes in heavy load the thread below causes high cpu

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpGenerator.flush(HttpGenerator.java:689)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:413)
at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Could this be reason that jetty server connector(blocking) and HttpClient connection(CONNECTOR_SELECT_CHANNEL )are different? Should they be same?

Comment: Jetty 6 was End-Of-Life'd back in 2010, there have been over 100 stable/final releases of Jetty since the last Jetty 6 release.  You have none of the updates/improvements/bug fixes/jvm fixes/and security fixes from the past 4 years.

Comment: The issue seems to be resolved by starting the jetty server in NIO instead of BIO. Is there any reason that if we have a jetty server and we are using proxy servlet also on the same server they both have to use same connector. Server to use NIO and for proxy as we have to use httpclient which also use CONNECTOR_SELECT_CHANNEL?